# D7: Form builder

Tags: forms, webforms

I have multiple services I want to connect to.  I would love to use the native webform  within Drupal, but I need to post each webform to different APIs.  For example, we have a lead management service where you can post First Name, Last Name, Email, text area to there API.  I'm unclear how to accomplish this within Drupal?  I cant seem to find a module or other code that will allow me to take advantage of this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Mac

Answer (score 0):

Each form using the Drupal API is just a HTML form generated with PHP.

Each form has a unique validation and submit handler if desired. Within each validation and/or submit handler you can choose what to do with the data just like any other form handler you would find in a custom PHP implementation.

So, create your form, create your submit handler, place API code in that submit handler hooking into Drupal where it makes sense and never where it doesn't.